# How do I group multiple individual Jenkins Nodes in one

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, cloudbees

I was thinking if of a scenario where Jenkins nodes are grouped into different groups. With intentions to give certain user-groups read access to node clusters.

Is this at all possible?

PS: I understand that node labels provide some sort of grouping but user groups cannot be added.

Have gone through some Jenkins plugins but i have not been able to find something that provides such option.

looking forward to some replies or other work arounds